# How would you add a column that only has a set choice of values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I wanted to add a column that could only be two values, for example, a column called 'Gender' with the two possible options of 'Male' or 'Female'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use **[`CHECK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

```
Gender VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL CHECK (Gender IN ('Male', 'Female'))
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03347)

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi ok, reduce to `VARCHAR(6)` :D

Answer (score 3):

I would probably want to use a bit field type, and not allow nulls, so that value can only be 0 or 1 (true/false).

Comment: this is also a very good answer but there are some possibilities wherein the OP wants to add a column that has 4 or greater possble values.

Answer (score 1):

```
 create table abc (
 Gender Varchar(10) check (gender in ('Female','Male'))
```

Comment: 9 minutes later than a working answer, same idea, you can't spell `table` and you choose exactly the same precision for varchar?